# jibx-maven-plugin 1.2.3 schema-codegen goal <schemaLocation> value ignored

Tags: maven-plugin, jibx

I am trying to use jibx-maven plugin 1.2.3 for generating Java Source Code from a Schema file.

Following is the plugin config in my pom.xml

```xml
<build>
<plugins>
    <!--
         To use the JiBX Maven Plugin in your project you have to add it 
         to the plugins section of your POM. 
     -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <schemaLocation>src/main/resources</schemaLocation>
                   <options>
                       <package>com.poc.jibx</package>
                   </options>
                </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
 </build>
```

When I try to run the goal using command: **mvn jibx:schema-codegen**

I get the following output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jibx-sample 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jibx-maven-plugin:1.2.3:schema-codegen (default-cli) @ jibx-sample ---
[INFO] Generating Java sources in target/generated-sources from schemas available in src/main/config...
Loaded and validated 0 specified schema(s)
Total classes in model: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.691s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Sep 22 20:11:33 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/71M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As can be seen in the output the default schema location is being searched for i.e. *src/main/config* instead of my the configured location **src/main/resources**.

I came across the following JIRA which says the the above plugin config is appropriate and should work prefectly.
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JIBX-450

However it is not working in my case.Am I missing anything else for making this work?

Thanks,
Jignesh

Comment: First i would suggest to try to locate the schemas into src/main/config second you already tried ...are your schemas names *.xsd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jignesh,

Actually, your first pom should have worked fine. khmarbaise is correct, it is considered good practice to place your schema definitions in the /src/main/config directory and make sure they have an .xsd extension.

Here is a corrected project file. I am using your schema location. Note the OSGi bundle packaging. This will work fine for non-OSGi projects, and your project is ready to go when you start using OSGi.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.poc.jibx</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-java-code-from-schema</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLocation>src/main/resources</schemaLocation>
                            <options>
                                <package>com.poc.jibx</package>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-binding</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bind</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaBindingDirectory>target/generated-sources</schemaBindingDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>binding.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Include-Resource>META-INF/binding.xml=${basedir}/target/generated-sources/binding.xml</Include-Resource>
                        <Export-Package>com.poc.jibx.*;version=${project.version}</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Good luck!

Don
jibx-maven-plugin project contributor

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved and I am posting the solution here so that it can help others, if they  face this issue:

The correct pom.xml should look like below

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.poc.jibx</groupId>
      <artifactId>jibx-sample</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>jibx-sample</name>

      <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                   <schemaLocation>src/main/conf</schemaLocation>
                   <includeSchemas>
                       <includeSchema><YOUR_SCHEMA_FILE_NAME>.xsd</includeSchema>
                   </includeSchemas>
                   <options>
                       <package>com.poc.jibx</package>
                   </options>
                   <schemaBindingDirectory>src/main/java</schemaBindingDirectory>          
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                        <id>generate-java-code-from-schema</id>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

In my first post the **plugin** section shows the **configuration** section inside the **execution** element while in the above code it is outside ***executions***

The code snippet I used earlier I took from the **sample usage** example shown at http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/schema-codegen.html

under section

## Generate Java Sources from Schemas and Compile Binding

### Java Sources from XSD Schemas

Here is below a ***sample usage***:

which I suppose is wrong and needs rectification.

**The correct code snippet is available under section**

## Generate Java Sources from Schemas

### Java Sources from XSD Schemas

Here is a **sample plugin section**:

Thanks,
Jignesh